# Converting Language Detection Score of CLD2 to CLD3 Accuracy

Tags: language-detection, cld2, cld3

My [cld2](https://github.com/CLD2Owners/cld2) language detection model (langID) returns for the input sentence to classify the following values

```
{ reliable: true,
  textBytes: 181,
  languages: 
   [ { name: 'ITALIAN', code: 'it', percent: 61, score: 774 },
     { name: 'ENGLISH', code: 'en', percent: 38, score: 1573 } ],
  chunks: 
   [ { name: 'ITALIAN', code: 'it', offset: 0, bytes: 116 },
     { name: 'ENGLISH', code: 'en', offset: 116, bytes: 71 } ] }
```

where the `textBytes` represents the size of the input text, `percent` the distribution of the `code` in the sentence, while the `score` is an indicator of the quality of the detection (the smaller it is the best it is).
That said, in the brand new [CLD3](https://github.com/google/cld3) neural network, the result of the classification is just the accuracy (so a probability value between 0 and 1) so like

```
 println(ld.getCode(0))
 println(ld.getScore(0))

en
0.99
```

I would like to figure out how to convert CLD2 score to probabilities values in order to compare the results to the new CLD3 model.

Comment: Loreto dear, just ping me and I will give you the contact of the researchers.

Comment: Link to the issue: https://github.com/google/cld3/issues/24

Comment: That would be amazing, thank you Adam.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer in my understanding in `CDL2` those probabilities value are internally here: https://github.com/dachev/node-cld/issues/52